# in an insert can postgres either return the id of the new row or an existing row on a unique index?

Tags: postgresql

I'm inserting words to a table where the word column has a unique index. I'm taking advantage of postgre's returning id feature to get the id of a new row, but if the insert fails due to an existing word, can postgres return the existing id?

Comment: You can use `on conflict do update`.  This is explained in the `insert` syntax:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html.

Comment: would using `on conflict` with action `do nothing` still return the existing id?

Comment: I don't think so.  Postgres wants to return something when a change is made.   You can try it though, because I might be wrong.